# Can Chirp Waves be sent using JSN-SR04T?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

So i have project for underwater rangefinding using JSN-SR04T. I've read on the datasheet that the module sends square waves. Is it possible to program it so that it sends Chirp waves instead ? (Help with the coding is very appreciated)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the data sheet say the module can send chirp waves?

Comment: no, it says it sends square waves

Comment: Well surely that was your answer?

Comment: This question is not about Arduino, this question can be better solved by contacting the supplier, this question shows no/little effort of the asker and is too broad (also asks help for "coding"). Please read https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange I'm voting to close, but please feel free to adjust your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As I googled the sensor, I found various sites stating, that a JSN-SR04T behaves exactly like the HC-SR04. The difference is mainly the water prooving.

So the answer is: No, you can't do this. The square wave, which drives the ultrasonic transducers, is generated by a hardware circuit and is not meant to be changed. To output a chirp wave you would need to rebuild the signal generation and measurement hardware (leaving only the transducers unchanged). At that point you may just buy the pure ultrasonic transducers and build the rest yourself.

Comment: Ok thank for the help

Comment: Ok, i also want to translate the distance data into a 3D image, how do you propose i do that ?

Comment: That depends on how you want to represent the image and how exactly you are measuring. Are you moving the sensor over a surface, or are you turning the sensor ro look in different directions?